# Windows Azure asp .Net f/w

Tags: asp.net, azure, azure-storage

Error   1   The type or namespace name 'ApplicationBlocks' does not exist in the namespace 'Microsoft' (are you missing an assembly reference?

Any Help

Comment: You need to spend some time on this question. Posting an error message and asking for help, with zero context, is not going to yield you an answer.

Answer (score 0):

Make sure you have the dll

```
Microsoft.ApplicationBlocks.Data.dll
```

Make sure the output is set to copy always to ensure it gets sent out as it will not be installed on any of the instances in Windows Azure in the GAC like it most likely is on your development machine.